# Adding metadata to an image in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, exif

I am creating an app to take an image and save the image to the camera roll but also adding a string of data to the metadata of the image at the same time and this string would mostly be a combination of user entered data in a couple of text fields. So I pick up an image using the camera of the iphone which is accessed by the UIImagePicker. Now I want to save this and edit the metadata before saving. I have looked up a solution but could not find a proper one for swift.